# Script load on xhr response

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest, load

i have problem with responseText.
I want to load script from includes/dodaj-slike.php (which is echo)

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
    if(this.readyState === 4) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
};

xhr.open('POST', 'includes/dodaj-slike.php', true);
xhr.send(formdata);
```

Alert **responseText** is (example) :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('ul li:nth(0)').append('<img src='uploads/cropped_2013-08-12 00.50.37.jpg'/>');
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('ul li:nth(1)').append('<img src='uploads/cropped_2013-08-18 12.56.24.jpg'/>');
</script>
```

I get this and I want to somehow load this script immediately after response.

**My question is how to load script on this way?**

Comment: `$()` is typically a jQuery function. Are you using jQuery?

Comment: @Machavity yes I'm using jQuery

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it with

```
document.head.appendChild(responseText);
```

Correct way would be as suggested

```
$("head").append(xhr.responseText);
```

Comment: [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild) takes a DOM node. He's returning raw HTML

Comment: @sushant do you have another idea?